# Threading in Java vs. C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I need a little confirmation over something I am confused at. I know how threads work in java:

```
new DialList(string a , string b).start(); // where DialList is a class

public class DialList extends Thread {
    public DialList(String a, string b) {
        FilePath = a; 
        ThreadLogFile = b"; 
    }

    public void run() {
        // some code to run in different thread
    }
}
```

Now I want to run the same code in C#. Shall I put the code which is in run() into a method and do something like:

```
 Thread t = new Thread (runcsharp);          // Kick off a new thread
 t.Start(); 
 static void runcsharp(parameters) {
     // code
 }
```

or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: There are *correct* ways to do it

Comment: Can you mention few ? and the problem with above method

Comment: What is `WriteY` in your C# code?

Comment: sorry it is runc# name of function

Comment: Is this code incomplete? It's a bit confusing.. If you're confused about how to run threads in .NET, perhaps you should start with looking at the managed ThreadPool instead of attempting your own.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to start a new thread in C#.  For example:

```
static void run()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteY));
    t.Start();   // Run WriteY on the new thread.
}

void WriteY()
{
    // do something
}
```

Note that this assumes that `WriteY` has no parameters.  If it did, you would have to use the [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) delegate. 
For detailed information, see Joe Albahari's excellent (and free) [ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Creating_and_Starting_Threads).

edit: if I understand this correctly, you have an object of type `DialList` that you want to pass to a new thread. You can do that in C# this way:

```
void WriteY(DialList dl)
{ // do something with the DialList
}

var dl = new DialList(AString, BString);
Thread T = new Thread( () => WriteY(dl) );
```

Comment: so there is not concept of Run() function in C# as is in java where start in turn calls the run() and code is placed in run

Comment: and writeY will have parameters

Answer (score 1):

I have a few observations:

Firstly, although your way of creating threads in java works, the recommended way is to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`. This gives you a lot more flexibility on where you can use the same code, since you could also feed it to an `ExecutorService` for example.

```
new Thread(new DialList(string a , string b)).start();

public class DialList implements Runnable {
    public DialList(String a, string b) {
        FilePath = a; 
        ThreadLogFile = b"; 
    }

    public void run() {
        // some code to run in different thread
    }
}
```

Second, yes you can use that snippet in C#, and you can also use lambda expressions:

```
Thread t = new Thread(
   o =>
   {
       // code
   });
t.Start();
```

Lambdas in C# are more powerful than anonymous classes in java because you can modify the captured variables. This can be convenient but it's also a good way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: It's worth noting though that in Java you can get back all (or approximately all) of the power that you lose with an anonymous class by just using a non-anonymous class.  Lambda's don't really add power so much as convenience as it takes so much less code (in terms of character count) than it does to create your own class that implements an interface and explicitly hoists all of the closed over local variables to fields.